# Monitoring latency in Kafka Streams

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

When [monitoring](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/streams/monitoring.html) the end-to-end latency of Kafka Streams, does it take any windowing periods into account or are they ignored?